# Science fiction short story in which Einstein is cloned but shows no interest in much except playing his violin

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this in the 90s. Based on the failure of getting anything productive out of the Einstein clone, future cloning targets are more engineering-minded like Poincare.

Answer (score 39):

Is it *[Out of Copyright](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48210)* by Charles Sheffield?

> That doesn’t mean [cloning] always works out well. The most famous case, of course, was Albert Einstein. When his copyright had expired in 2030, BP Megation had had first choice in the draft pick. They had their doubts, and they must have sweated blood over their decision. The rumor mill said they spent over $70 million in simulations alone, before they decided to take him as their top choice. The same rumor mill said that the cloned form was now showing amazing ability in chess and music, but no interest at all in physics or mathematics. If that was true, BP Megation had dropped $2 billion down a black hole: $1 billion straight to the PNU for acquisition of copyright, and another $1 billion for the clone process. Theorists were always tricky; you could never tell how they would turn out.

See [Short story about public-domain clones of historical figures](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/254062/82909) (which has this quote and a lot more from the story).

Comment: if correct, this would be a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/254062/short-story-about-public-domain-clones-of-historical-figures

Answer (score 4):

I remember a book just like this! I don't think it was about Albert Einstein though. It was called *[House of the Scorpion](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_House_of_the_Scorpion)* by Nancy Farmer.

It took place in Mexico, this guy there was making clones of himself to farm for organs, and this specific clone was the only one that took after his early onset love for music.

Comment: I remember this book well, but I don't think it really matches the description in the question here. (Admittedly the question doesn't have much detail, so several different stories might match, and I've downvoted it for that reason.)